# Search html table and write specific row/column with php

Tags: php, html, search, html-table

I made a code that reads a table from another website and writes it on mine. Now I want to read just specific rows/columns and write it on my site. The table is filled with weather data and it refreshes every 5 minutes. I need only values for full and half hours and not all the values in the row, but just temperature. For example, there's a row for every five minutes containing temperature value, humidity, sun radiation etc. I need to find a value of, let's say 05:00, and read/write only temperature column of that row. In this case it would be: 05:00    12,5°C. And I need 48 values, because there's 24 hours per day and including another 24 half hours it's 48 all together, right..

This is a part of my code:

```
<?php

$trazi = ':00';
$citaj = file('proba.txt');
foreach($citaj as $linija)
{
  if(strpos($linija, $trazi) !== false)
   echo $linija;
}

$traziURL = "somepage";
$stranica = file_get_contents($traziURL);
$tablica = '/(<table.*<\/table>)/s';
preg_match_all($tablica, $stranica, $zeit);
echo $zeit[0][0];
$ime = "proba.txt";
$table = fopen($ime, 'w') or die ("Error!");
$podaci = $zeit[0][0];

fwrite($table, $podaci);
fclose($table);

?>
```

There's a chance that it won't work for you 'cause some parts are missing, but just to give you the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are multiple other ways to do this, but I'd do it like this.

```
<?php

/**
 * @author Bart Degryse
 * @copyright 2013
 */

function getData() {
  //Get the html page
  $url = "http://www.essen-wetter.de/table.php";
  $content = file_get_contents($url);

  //Turn it into a dom document searchable by xpath
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  $dom->loadHTML($content);
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

  //Get field names
  $query = "//tr/td[position()=1 and normalize-space(text()) = 'Zeit']";
  $entries = $xpath->query($query);
  $entry = $entries->item(0);
  $tr = $entry->parentNode;
  foreach ($tr->getElementsByTagName("td") as $td) {
    $fieldnames[] = $td->textContent;
  }

  //Get field data
  $query = "//tr/td[position()=1 and (substring-after(normalize-space(text()),':') = '00' or substring-after(normalize-space(text()),':') = '30')]";
  $entries = $xpath->query($query);
  foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $fieldvalues = array();
    $tr = $entry->parentNode;
    foreach ($tr->getElementsByTagName("td") as $td) {
      $fieldvalues[] = $td->textContent;
    }
    $data[] = array_combine($fieldnames, $fieldvalues);
  }

  //Return data set
  return $data;
}

//Gather the data
$data = getData();

//Do something with it
echo "<pre>\n";
foreach ($data as $row) {
  echo "Temperature at {$row['Zeit']} was {$row['Temperatur']}.\n";
}
echo "</pre><hr><pre>\n";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>\n";
?>
```

If you're going to display the data on a UTF-8 compatible terminal or on a web page that's declared as being UTF-8 encoded this should do it.
If you're want to use single-byte ISO-8859-1 encoding however you'll have to change this line:

```
    $fieldnames[] = $td->textContent;
```

into this:

```
    $fieldvalues[] = utf8_decode($td->textContent);
```

**Remark**
Please note that while doing this is technically not that hard legally you're on loose ground. The data on that page is copyrighted and owned by Markus Wolter. Using his data for your own purposes without his consent is considered theft.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Works great! The site I'm working on is not online, it's just some project that I'm working on using Xampp so I just used this web site because it's table fits my needs. Thanks for the heads up, anyway! I'll just remove it and make my own!

Comment: Sure! The "Do something with it" part is just an example. It's basically up to you to decide how to use the gathered data. Use this to show the data in sentences `echo "<pre>\n"; foreach ($data as $row) { echo "Temperature at {$row['Zeit']} was {$row['Temperatur']}.\n"; } echo "</pre>";`
Or to write to a tab delimited file use something like
`foreach ($data as $row) { file_put_contents('myfile.txt', "{$row['Zeit']}\t{$row['Temperatur']}\n", FILE_APPEND); }`